# Multiple conditions for switch in javascript

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

How can I set multiple conditions for switch statement in JS?

or How to set or condition inside switch?

eg:

```
switch(apple.amount) or switch(orange.amount)
{

case '1 kg':
total = 100;
break;

case '2 kg':
 total = 200;
break;
}
```

Comment: And exactly how would this work if both have values?

Comment: Encapsulate your switch in a function and pass both amounts to said function.

Comment: Either one have value at a time.

Comment: Do you mean `switch(apple.amount || orange.amount)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `loop`:

```
var amounts = [apple.amount, orange.amount];
var totals = [];
for(var i = 0; i < amounts.length; i++){
    switch(amounts[i])
    {
        case '1 kg':
        totals[i] = 100;
        break;

        case '2 kg':
        totals[i] = 200;
        break;
    }
}
```

If your certain that only one will have a value during any execution you can use the `||` operator:

```
var amount1;
var amount2 = '2 kg';
var total;

    switch(amount1 || amount2 )
    {
        case '1 kg':
        total = 100;
        break;

        case '2 kg':
        total = 200;
        break;
    }

alert(total);
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the switch in a function and test the return value:

```
function getTotal(amount) {
  switch(amount) {
    case '1 kg':
      return 100
    case '2 kg':
      return 200
  }
}
if(getTotal(apple.amount) || getTotal(orange.amount)) {
    // both returns a total
}
```